# I'm not sure how to properly implement Google Passport on both the frontend and backend (NestJs, React), particularly what data to send from frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, nestjs, passport.js

To sum things up, I have the strategy implemented on the server side and a function that makes a call from the frontend (I'm using @react-oauth/google). I'm unclear on what I need to send in that call to bypass the protection on the server.

*NestJS*

googleStrategy

```js
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, "google") {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    // parameters
  ) {
    return done(null, profile);
  }
}
```

googleGuard

```js
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthGuard extends AuthGuard("google") {}
```

I have imported strategy inside my auth module as my provider.

React

```js
  <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={clientId}>
    <GoogleLogin
      onSuccess={async (credentialResponse) => {
        try {
          const access_token = credentialResponse.credential;
          const response = await axios.post("/api/auth/google/callback", {
            access_token,
            clientId,
          });
          console.log(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
          if (error instanceof Error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        }
      }}
      onError={() => {
        console.log("Login Failed");
      }}
    />
  </GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

credentialResponse contains the credential token, clientId, and selectBy. If I send this object, I get a CORS error. If I separate the token into access_token and send it along with the clientId in the object, the error remains the same:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&client_id=528264268525-o389pk0dilsdk7bdqhduds3aqletigaj.apps.googleusercontent.com'
> (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google/callback')
> from origin 'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I've enabled CORS for the application, so I'm certain that the Google Passport implementation is causing the issue.

```js
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
```